# Sidebar to Focus on Specific Cell

Tags: html, google-apps-script, sidebar

Trying to use a sidebar as a navigation bar for a few cells as I have a rather large database spreadsheet.  I have a few links within the sidebar that when clicked should select a certain cell.

The thing is that I would like to create only ONE function at most that passes an argument e.g.:

```
<a onclick="goto('A20');">Go to A20</a>
```

Alternatively, I would like to include the single line of code inside of the html tag if possible.

Any hope would be greatly appreciated, thank you all in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Specifically mentioned in the Apps Script ["Guide" for sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) on the Apps Script documentation site is... **[Client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)**. You need to read it (you should have already read it as a part of researching your question).

Comment: I'm agree with @tehhowch . You should avoid such questions as it contradicts the rules of the community.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimum set of code for the application.

### Code.gs

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("A")
  .addItem("B", "showSidebar")
  .addToUi();  
}

function showSidebar(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Sidebar"));
}

function goto(a1Notation){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection(a1Notation);
}
```

### Sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:google.script.run.goto('A20');">Go to A20</a><br />
    <a href="javascript:google.script.run.goto('A20:C1');">Go to A20:C1</a><br />
    <a href="javascript:google.script.run.goto('A2');">Go to A2</a><br />
  </body>
</html>
```